# Count openoffice pages between documents

Tags: macros, openoffice.org

I have two odt files A and B, where the file A has n pages, and the B m pages. It is possible to get the number of pages of A (n) using macros in B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the page count of the current document:

```vb
MsgBox ThisComponent.CurrentController.PageCount
```

So instead of ThisComponent, load another document and get the page count from that component.  [Andrew's Macro Document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php) section 5.8.2 explains how to load another document.